# Cancel BackgroundWorker while waiting for a WMI notification event

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wmi, backgroundworker

I have a `BackgroundWorker` that watches for a WMI notification event to fire. My query looks something like `SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' AND TargetInstance.Name=proccessnamehere`. This query polls for an __InstanceDeletionEvent that meet the WHERE conditions every 2 seconds. Sometimes the process I’m watching takes a while, delaying the event from firing and i would like to cancel it. Everything I’ve read about cancelling BackgroundWorker suggest i use a loop of some sort. However, I’m not sure how to include a loop during a notification event. Is there an alternative way to do this? I played around with a timer but no success

**Edit: Code Sample - removed unrelated code**

(This will execute against a remote computer)

```
using System.Management;
private void backGroundWorkerStart_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        object[] args = e.Argument as object[];
        string computerName = args[0].ToString();
        string processName = args[1].ToString();

        ConnectionOptions con = new ConnectionOptions();
        con.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
        con.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Default;
        con.EnablePrivileges = true;

        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format(@"\\{0}\ROOT\CIMV2", computerName), con);

        scope.Connect();

        WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery(String.Format("SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' AND TargetInstance.Name='{0}'", processName));
        ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, query);

        ManagementBaseObject baseObject = watcher.WaitForNextEvent();
    }
```

Comment: Can you post a (possibly simplified) version of your current code?

Comment: @EricJ. Added a simplified sample. Hope this is what you requested.

Answer (score 1):

You can't force the termination of a background worker immediately (without using cancellation pending flag), it simply isn't designed in that way.

[Task Parallel Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152765/Task-Parallel-Library-of-n) provides that feature.

If you really want to use a BackgroundWorker and achieve your goal below is an option. Probably not the best way to do it..

You can get the get the Thread the BackgroundWorker is running on in the DoWork event save it in a field and you can then abort the thread.

```
private Thread _backgroundWorkerThread;

public void StartBackgroundWorker()
{
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker.DoWork += DoWork;
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

public void AbortBackgroundWorker()
{
    if(_backgroundWorkerThread != null)
        _backgroundWorkerThread.Abort();
}

void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        _backgroundWorkerThread = Thread.CurrentThread;

        // Do your work...
    }
    catch(ThreadAbortException)
    {
        // Do your clean up here.
    }
}
```

Reference [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/244729/csharp-BackgroundWorker-cancelling-problem) for more options

**Edit**

May be you are looking for something like below.

```
WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery(String.Format("SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' AND TargetInstance.Name='{0}'", processName));
            ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, query);

            ManagementBaseObject baseObject = watcher.WaitForNextEvent();

            if (myBackgroundWorkder.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                watcher.Stop();
                return 0;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm aware i can't force terminate the thread. I do know by the examples provided on MSDN that i can set up a loop to watch for the CancellationPending flag to turn to True then set the CancelEventArgs.Canel = True which should trigger the thread to end. I can't figure out how to set up a loop to check for the CancellationPending  flag to change.

Comment: @HiTech: Have a look at my update. May be you are looking for something like that...

Comment: Thanks for that edit. The problem with running the check after watcher.WaitForNextEvent() is that it doesn't run until the event is fired. Which is to late.

Comment: If that's my only option it might be better if i just remotely kill the process and let the thread the event watcher is on end naturally. Thanks for your help @CharithJ